# How to create a group input to resize the grid based on the instanced object size as default size (Grid->Mesh to Points->Instance on Points)?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am new to Blender Geometry Nodes and am trying to figure out how to resize the grid size X and Y values as vertex X and Y to eliminate the spaces between instanced objects as default size. It would be much appreciated if someone could shed some light on this.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you mean - to create a grid of instanced objects and to arrange them in that grid with minimum distance between them? Like - 2x4 grid of cubes with no space between them.